# line spacing in cell of tabular and left-aligned in tabular

Tags: tabularx, line-spacing

I want to reduce line spacing in all cells of a table and also want to have left-aligned in cells with `p{5cm}` option (first column of the table). I know that I should adjust with `\setlength{\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}`, but don't know where I should put the code in. Can anyone give me a hint? I have a code as following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsbsy, array}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
\definecolor{battleshipgrey}{rgb}{0.52, 0.52, 0.51}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Ph.D. timeline}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf{Task and Activities}}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|} 
 {\cellcolor{bleudefrance}\textcolor{white}{\bf{2020}}} &\multicolumn{4}{|c|} 
 {\cellcolor{bleudefrance}\textcolor{white}{\bf{2021}}}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|} 
 {\cellcolor{bleudefrance}\textcolor{white}{\bf{2022}}} \\ \cline{2-11}
         &Q1    &Q2 &Q3 &Q4 &Q1 &Q2 &Q3 &Q4 &Q1 &Q2  \\ \cline{1-11}
  Dissertation Design Seminar & & \cellcolor{americanrose} & && && &  & & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Data collection & & \cellcolor{battleshipgrey} &\cellcolor{battleshipgrey}& & & & &  & & \\ 
  \cline{1-11}
  Data cleaning \& Analysis & & &&\cellcolor{battleshipgrey} & & & &  & & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Post fieldwork seminar & & && & \cellcolor{americanrose}& & &  & & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Finalizing $2^{nd}$ chapter & &\cellcolor{battleshipgrey}&\cellcolor{battleshipgrey}&& & & &  & & 
  \\ \cline{1-11}
  Conference papers/ Draft chapters  & & & & & &\cellcolor{ao}& &  & & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Finalizing $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ chapters & & & & 
  &\cellcolor{battleshipgrey}&\cellcolor{battleshipgrey}& &  & & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Writing introduction and conclusion & & & & &&&\cellcolor{battleshipgrey}&  & & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Full draft seminar & & & & &&&&\cellcolor{americanrose}& & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Submission of the thesis & & & & &&&&&\cellcolor{americanrose} & \\ \cline{1-11}
  Defense the thesis & & & & &&&&& &\cellcolor{americanrose} \\ \cline{1-11}
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: The  `p{5cm}` column will be by default justified, hence left aligned. Is  it in these cells that you want to reduce linespacing?

Comment: To the left (the default, as Bernard said) or to the right?  `>{\raggedleft}p{5cm}` and `\tabcolsep1pt` (obviously, before tabular) help?

Comment: And what does the horizontal alignment with `\baselineskip`? The `\baselineskip` is always `1\baselineskip` untill you say it's something else. In this example have no sense this setting.

Comment: @Bernard yes, I want to reduce line spacing to 0.8 of the defraud in these cells  (cells that are formatted with p{5cm}. Also left-aligned, not justified. Thanks Bernard.

Comment: Use `>{\linespread{0.8}\raggedright}p{5cm}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!